# Would logging request individually good practice or clutter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

I am working on a API, which make a lot of calls, some of them need to be thoroughly logged for various reasons.

For now, I log all input/output/processing happening in the function, and the API works flawlessly, so there doesn't seems to be a need to increase the amount of logging.

But a idea that scratch the back of my mind is to assign a UUID to each incoming API call, which would follow the logging in the inner functions.

While it would create a fair amount of additionals parameters to follow the UUID in each functions, I am wondering if it is common practice, and if I should implement it before the need arise, and while the amount of change to do is manageable.

Ex:

*Obviously the real code is far more complicated, and doesn't use `console.log` for logging*

```
const express = require('express'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    config = require('./config.json'),
    app = express();

function foo(bar, callback) {
    console.log(bar);
    fs.open(bar, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.err(err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data)
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    foo(req.body.bar, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.err(err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log(result)
            res.send(null, result);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(config.port);
```

To:

```
const express = require('express'),
    UUID = require('uuid-generator'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    config = require('./config.json'),
    app = express();

function foo(uuid, bar, callback) {
    console.log(uuid + ': ' + bar);
    fs.open(bar, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
            console.err(uuid + ': ' + err);
            callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log(uuid + ': ' + data)
            callback(null, data);
        }
    });
}

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    req.id = new UUID();
    next();
});

app.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.id + ': ' + req.body);
    foo(req.id, req.body.bar, (err, result) => {
        if(err) {
            console.err(req.id + ': ' + err);
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log(req.id + ': ' + result)
            res.send(null, result);
        }
    });
});

app.listen(config.port);
```

The pro would be that, in case a function fail, or in case of a system crash, we could identify precisely which call caused the error, and which path it followed more easily.

The con is, it need a not negligible amount of work to implement, and may not be that useful, since we can already deduce the path followed from the different input/output and other logging already implemented.

**TL:DR**: Is it common practice to log each request with such a level of granularity, or is it reserved for specific use case?

Is there any tools that automate that away and I should not care about it in the code?

Answer (score 1):

I can’t really comment on whether this is common practice in general but it has been fairly common practice on the products that I’ve worked on recently.

Depending on the use case I can see a lot of value in tracing a single request through a system. High traffic APIs tend to benefit from this, as do systems composed of microservices where you might need to trace a request through a number connecting services.

For example, if you have an API that takes input that needs to be stored it can be very useful to be able to correlate the specific input data to a failed database write.

If you decide that you do want to add a UUID to your requests then the [express-request-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-request-id) middleware is a useful module which generates a UUID for you and will add it to the response headers. It can also take an UUID if present on the incoming request header and use that instead, which is useful for tracing requests between services.

I’ve not seen anything for node that will abstract logging individual requests entirely away but I haven’t looked for that.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to log requests but not to stdout/stderr or file. Best way is to send it to something like Logz.io or own Logstash instance (could be installed on same or different machine) through TCP socket. Logstash should be connected to managed AWS Elasticsearch service or one that is installed locally or on remote machine. 
If the amount of logs is not big this could be assembled very fast using docker-compose (for high throughput i recommend dedicated resourceful server)

ELK Stack is awesome toolset for monitoring, log aggregation, advansed queries in order to find specific request and details about it though thousands of thousands of log entries. It is search-oriented nosql database, which already almost became industry's one of most advanced log aggregation facilities.

Logstash recieves logs through different protocols, sends them to NoSQL Elasticsearch, and then You can browse, build dashboards, and aggregate your log data using Kibana front end.

There is a reason to add X-Request-Id header as been suggested already, and other infrastructure metadata to your logs, and time metrics.

**Here is the project which will allow you to setup whole ELK toolset on your local machine**
https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk

Logging could be done with help of:
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston (using https://www.npmjs.com/package/winston-logstash)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan (with https://www.npmjs.com/package/bunyan-logstash)

Both libraries have tons of plugins for other kind of logging

Comment: I want to follow the request inside the server, the calls made to answer it. I do not need to follow it between different servers. Also, Logging is already sent to a server, I used `console.log` to not show the code connecting to and setting up the log format.

Comment: you can try this:a multi-transport async logging library for node.js http://github.com/winstonjs/winston

Comment: You can use some kind of module for logging - like `winston` - they have alot of plug ins that support very different transports and dedicated solely for that puprose - to configure logging, to log uncaughtExceptions, to create proper access logs (that what you want). ELK could be local - simply according to what you require in your OP - thats a perfect match. Locally ELK could installed in very simple manner - using docker-compose .

Comment: @Caspain ha we made post about it in same moment

Comment: Added link to very helpful link for you in my answer

Comment: @SlavikJacobson: In my experience logging to file then have logstash parse that file (or even better, filebeat) reduces network overhead by quite a lot because you can send logs in batches. It's also an architecture that devops are move familiar with allowing them to manage logging without needing to make code change request

Comment: @slebetman I understand and agree with  your reasoning, but there are cases where my solution is more fitting or at least more pragmatic - because it needs less configuration and more dynamic - lets say we have dynamic amount of dockerized microservices and dockerized logstash - logstash container (there are alot of advantages keeping it within same network under 'logstash' host name and not as configurable external dependency) will require to get more files introduced on the fly. It creates big overhead.. It's all is matter of case, architecture, resource limitiations (Mem vs CPU vs IO)

Answer (score 0):

1. have you looked into [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan).
   It is express middleware to log every request in file, db etc.
   Probably you can even throw logs to logstash.
2. Now, rather than passing UUID to every function as separate argument, pass it in existing data json being passed to every function.

i think you should change your code to include uuid in every log message because it will help you very much to focus on trail of particular request in large log files based on uuid.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The problem is that I will not pass the full request to every function, because that would break readability, what I want is a clean way to access that id from every function without having to pass it explicitely and cluttering my code. Morgan seems good, but doesn't solve the whole problem.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Hi, i m not talking to pass req object to every function to call, to talking just pass the uuid as extra value in current json being passed to function as argument.

Comment: @DrakaSAN If same thing is to be achieved in java, we use local cache of thread in which current request in executing. we achieved the same in node application which i am currently working on.